# Disappearing code?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, designer

I'm working on a project where I want to load information based on the selection in a dataGridView. I created a dataGridView in the designer of my form and I added this line:

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += methodToBeCalled;
```

This all works fine, but I have one nasty problem. Most of the time when I start my application there's nothing happening after selecting a row. Then, when I look in my code, the line of code has disappeared completely.

First I thought somebody committed some code over mine, but even when I don't update it disappears.

What could be the reason (bug/visual studio design) for the disappearing code? How could I fix it?

Comment: Best title ever

Comment: Are you perhaps putting that into an area where auto-generated code is? if so it recreates the code every time overwriting your code

Comment: This is a bug and unfortunately the Microsoft have nothing to do with this kind of strange disappearing code :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are placing it in the .designer.cs file correct?  This is wrong.  It has to be placed in your normal code behind screen.  The .designer file can be re-generated whenever the system wants to.